# undefined: SQLiteConn when trying to build go app for armv7

Tags: go, arm, cross-compiling

I have to compile a Go service for Ubuntu ARM-v7

When I compile it with

```
GOARCH=arm GOARM=7 go build -v -o release/edge_to_bc -ldflags '-s -w -extldflags "-static"' ./...
```

I get:

```
gitlab.com/company/edge_to_bc/vendor/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/bccsp/pkcs11
# gitlab.com/company/edge_to_bc/vendor/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/bccsp/pkcs11
vendor/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/bccsp/pkcs11/impl.go:82:12: undefined: pkcs11.Ctx
vendor/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/bccsp/pkcs11/impl.go:83:16: undefined: pkcs11.SessionHandle
gitlab.com/company/edge_to_bc/vendor/github.com/mattn/go-sqlite3
# gitlab.com/company/edge_to_bc/vendor/github.com/mattn/go-sqlite3
vendor/github.com/mattn/go-sqlite3/sqlite3_go18.go:18:10: undefined: SQLiteConn
vendor/github.com/mattn/go-sqlite3/sqlite3_go18.go:26:10: undefined: SQLiteConn
vendor/github.com/mattn/go-sqlite3/sqlite3_go18.go:27:17: undefined: namedValue
vendor/github.com/mattn/go-sqlite3/sqlite3_go18.go:29:13: undefined: namedValue
vendor/github.com/mattn/go-sqlite3/sqlite3_go18.go:35:10: undefined: SQLiteConn
vendor/github.com/mattn/go-sqlite3/sqlite3_go18.go:44:10: undefined: SQLiteConn
vendor/github.com/mattn/go-sqlite3/sqlite3_go18.go:49:10: undefined: SQLiteConn
vendor/github.com/mattn/go-sqlite3/sqlite3_go18.go:54:10: undefined: SQLiteStmt
vendor/github.com/mattn/go-sqlite3/sqlite3_go18.go:63:10: undefined: SQLiteStmt
vendor/github.com/mattn/go-sqlite3/tracecallback_noimpl.go:8:10: undefined: SQLiteConn
vendor/github.com/mattn/go-sqlite3/sqlite3_go18.go:29:13: too many errors
```

How should I fix it ?

Comment: `sqlite3` is a C library, and `github.com/mattn/go-sqlite3` uses cgo. Do you have the full toolchain to cross-compile a C package?

Comment: what do you mean by full toolchain ?

Comment: I have gcc-arm-linux-gnueabihf installed

Comment: I'm not sure if it needs any more libs, but try enabling CGO and set that as the target compiler.

Answer (score 2):

Go-sqlite3 is **cgo package**.

If you want to build your app using go-sqlite3, you need gcc.

However, after you have built and installed go-sqlite3 with go install github.com/mattn/go-sqlite3 (which requires gcc), you can build your app without relying on gcc in future.

Important: because this is a CGO enabled package you are required to set the environment variable **CGO_ENABLED=1** and have a **gcc compile present within your path**.

[Source](https://github.com/mattn/go-sqlite3)

Cross compiling **from Ubuntu** to ARM7:

```
sudo apt install \
 libc6-armel-cross \
 libc6-dev-armel-cross \
 binutils-arm-linux-gnueabi \
 libncurses5-dev \
 gcc-arm-linux-gnueabihf

env CC=arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc CXX=arm-linux-gnueabihf-g++ \
    CGO_ENABLED=1 GOOS=linux GOARCH=arm GOARM=7 \
    go build -v
```

Using a docker image:

```
# Install docker
$ curl -fsSL https://get.docker.com -o get-docker.sh | sudo sh -
$ sudo usermod -aG docker your-user

# Go to your project folder
$ cd your-project-folder

# Compile
$ docker run --rm \
    -v /tmp/.docker/go:/go \
    -v /tmp/.docker/go-build:/root/.cache/go-build \
    -v $PWD:$PWD \
    -w $PWD \
    filipeandre/go-compiler-to-arm7:1.12 \
    go build -v
```

[Dockerfile](https://gist.github.com/filipeandre/91b2167ec2f58f599cb3914b5e703fc2)

Comment: Now I get: `# gitlab.com/sunchain/edge_to_bc/vendor/github.com/miekg/pkcs11
/usr/lib/gcc-cross/arm-linux-gnueabihf/8/../../../../arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/ld: cannot find -lltdl
/usr/lib/gcc-cross/arm-linux-gnueabihf/8/../../../../arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/ld: cannot find -lltdl`

Comment: @JuliatzindelToro you may try the docker way :)

Comment: I'm also trying to docker way in parallel, via GitlabCI, using armv7/armhf-ubuntu docker image, but I can't install go as there is no wget, curl, and apt-get doesnt work... Other problems !

Comment: @JuliatzindelToro, the docker instructions I put in the response don't work for you ?

Comment: I get a dependency error when doing go build... `lora-peer.go:11:2: cannot find package "github.com/gin-gonic/gin" in any of:...` It is weird, because vendor folder is already generated

Comment: I'll upvote your question, because I think you are quite helpful, and proposing a lot of solutions.

Comment: I could do it: You have to do : `dpkg --add-architecture armhf && apt update && apt install apt install libltdl-dev:armhf ` 
`